# Как указать на какую кнопку нажимать при Enter?

Tags: html, вёрстка

есть форма и чекбосы. В зависимости от метода доставки, форма либо отправляет данные либо переводят на страницу оплаты. Кнопки разные и скрываются через JS. Но сейчас заметил что если выбираю вариант, и кликаю не на кнопку, а отправляю по средствам нажатия Enter, нажимается скрытая кнопка. Подскажите от чего зависит на какую кнопку будет работать ENTER и как поменять?

Comment: Обычно input type = submit принимает Enter

Comment: Если у вас элементы формы имеют обработчики, вероятно срабатывает фокус и получается, что вы нажимая `Enter` инициируете событие, привязанное к элементу, который находится в фокусе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналогичный вопрос был задан ранее [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission), и в качестве примера приведён следующий код:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Enter" срабатывает событие onsubmit, которое в Вашем случае должно перехватываться в Вашем коде.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateMyForm()
{
  if(check if your conditions are not satisfying)
  { 
    alert("validation failed false");
    returnToPreviousPage();
    return false;
  }

  alert("validations passed");
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Если вы используете JQuery:

```
$('#form').submit(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    //Ваша логика
});
```